# What is correct way to pass parameters to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple catalog:

```html
<?php foreach ($productArray as $key => $value) { ?>
    <div class="product">
        <form id="cartForm">
            <table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpading='2' width='300 px' align='center'>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td> 
                    <td><?php echo $productArray[$key]["ID"];?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>kategorija</td>
                    <td><?php echo $productArray[$key]["category"];?></td>
                </tr>
                    <td>kiekis</td>
                    <td><?php echo $productArray[$key]["quantity"];?></td>
                </tr>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="inputQuantity_<?php echo $productArray[$key] ["ID"];?>"/>
                    <input type="button" id="add_<?php echo $productArray[$key]["ID"];?>" value="prideti" onClick="cartAction('add','<?php echo $productArray[$key]["ID"];?>')" />
```

By pressing this button I want to pass array parameters to my `cartAction` function.

```
function cartAction(action, productID) {
    var stringQuery = "";

    if ($.trim(action) == 'add') {
        stringQuery= 'action=' + action + '&ID=' + productID + '&quantity=' + $("#inputQuantity_" + productID).val();
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        data: stringQuery,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Instead of array parameters `alert(data)` shows the full page code. What is the best way to collect array data and send to javascript function?

Comment: post your index.php page

Comment: maybe the data in your ajax should be an object/array: {action: action, ID: productID } etc/etc/etc

Comment: Just use json_encode for PHP array and pass json object to function.

Answer (score 0):

```
          <?php  foreach ($productArray as $key => $value) {   ?>

            <div class="product">
              <form  >
              <table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpading='2' width='300 px' align='center'>
              <tr>
                <td> ID </td> <td><?=$value["ID"];?> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> kategorija </td> <td><?=$value["category"];?> </td>
                </tr>
                <td> kiekis </td> <td><?=$value["quantity"];?> </td>
              </tr>
            <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?=$value["ID"];?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="category" value="<?=$value["category"];?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?=$value["quantity"];?>"/>
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="prideti"  />
         </form>
        <?php   } ?>


        <script>
        $(function(){
     $('.submit').click(function(){
                   data = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
        jQuery.ajax({
         url:"index.php",
         data:stringQuery,
         type:"POST",
         success: function(data){
             alert(data);
         }
        });
        return false ;
      });
    });
        </script>
```

Comment: this will send blank data to index.php

Comment: you have to set hidden fields for your every loop

Comment: you are serialising into the var `data` but sending the var `stringQuery`, thus an empty(well, undefined) data set

Answer (score 0):

Please pass json not create a string.

```
stringQuery = {"action":action,"ID":productID,"quantity":$("#inputQuantity_"+productID).val()}
```

Comment: that is an object, not json.

Comment: is called as json object

Comment: no, it's a javascript object.  json is simply a string notating an object.  you've explicitly set stringQuery as a javascript object, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

because you are using a string query, it looks like you'll find your data in the `$_GET` array instead of `$_POST`

If you want to use `$_POST`, then build your data as an object instead:

```
function cartAction(action, productID){
    if($.trim(action)=='add'){
        stringQuery= {
            'action': action,
            'ID': productID,
            'quantity': $("#inputQuantity_"+productID).val()
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            data: stringQuery,
            dataType: 'json', //so ajax knows how to populate the response
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) { alert(data); }
        });
    }
}
```

depending on how your index.php is written, you need to check if $_POST['action'] is set at the beginning and if so, handle your validation etc as well as performing the action(mysql, etc, etc) and then stop execution before the whole page html is output.

any data you want to output can be output using `json_encode()` in php.

also, instead of `alert(data)` in javascript, you might want to use `console.log(data)` and use developer tools to see what's in it (F12, then the console tab)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this script with your script.

```
function cartAction(action, productID){



     var stringQuery="";

        if($.trim(action)=='add'){

}

jQuery.ajax({

url:"index.php",
data:{"action":action,"ID":productID,"quantity":$("#inputQuantity_"+productID).val()},
type:"POST",

success: function(data){
alert(data);

}
});
}

</script>
```

Comment: i'm not sure what this does.  it seems to perform an ajax query even if the action isn't add.

Answer (score 0):

@Darius92

As per your question the way you asked, ***instead of array parameters alert(data) show full page code***, I believe that you are assuming the variable '`data`' in `alert(data)` will refer to `data` in line `data:stringQuery`. Is that So? 
**If I'm correct with your assumption, you are wrong!** 
The variable `data` in `success: function(data){alert(data); }` used to handle the response from your `url:"index.php",`. It means it is the response from your AJAX file (`index.php`).

You should print the `$_REQUEST` Array in your AJAX file, `index.php` to know what information has been posted to your `AJAX request`.

Your `AJAX handler file, index.php` should read like below:

```
<?php
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_REQUEST);
 echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I think you realized what you written and what you are expecting !

Answer (score 0):

you can use json as well instead of string see below

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: hb_base_url + "consumer",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        first_name: $("#namec").val(),
        last_name: $("#surnamec").val(),
        email: $("#emailc").val(),
        mobile: $("#numberc").val(),
        password: $("#passwordc").val()
    }),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

in this ajax request **contentType** means in which format you are sending the request data and **dataType** means in which formate you are expecting data

in this code passed json which is the good way